# Trouble defining RegEx pattern for a substring with repeated instances

Tags: python, sql, regex

I'm relatively new to RegEx and have been looking through various tutorials but struggling to understand how to put together the pattern I need.

Currently I have a string of SQL that includes repeated instances of this pattern:

```
,coalesce(column1,null) AS table_name.column1
```

`table_name` could be any name given that there are multiple tables involved in the overall SQL code.  What I'm trying to do is eliminate `table_name` from each occurrence of this pattern.  I'm thinking as long as I can identify the positions of `AS` and the `.` then the characters in between can be replaced with "".

Would I be incorrect in that method?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://regex101.com/r/fYwQ7d/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do a global replacement on:

```
\bAS\s*\S+?\.(\S+)
```

and use the first capture group as the replacement.

Sample script:

```
inp = ",coalesce(column1,null) AS table_name.column1"
out = re.sub(r'\bAS\s*\S+?\.(\S+)', '\\1', inp)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
,coalesce(column1,null) column1
```

Note that this regex search is fairly robust, as the `AS` keyword in SQL is mainly used to mark aliases.